# Import all text files in folder into Excel one at a time then move files

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to develop a macro that does the following

1. Imports a text file from DIRECTORY 1 into my active workbook to a particular sheet
2. Copies the extracted data from that imported text file and pastes the values into another worksheet (I have to perform some calculations)
3. Moves the imported file to DIRECTORY 2
4. Go back to step 1 for the next text file in DIRECTORY 1

I don't want to copy all the text files at once into one worksheet because there won't always be the same number of text files.

```
Sub Import()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Clear previous data

    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear
    Range("A1").Select

' Import text file

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;\\directory\test.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete

' Copy values to main data table

    Sheet3.Range("A2:P2").Copy

    Sheet6.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheet6.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I've got step 2 developed, and I've got step 1 developed for just a single file. It's the looping through all the files one at a time and moving the file once the data's imported that I'm lost with. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the Dir function to get each of the files and the Name function to move them.

```
Sub Import()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Clear previous data

    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear
    Range("A1").Select
'variables for paths and file name
Dim currentPath As String
Dim newPath As String
Dim currentFile As String
currentPath = "\\directory\"
newPath = "\\NewDirectory\"
'get the first file
 currentFile = Dir(currentPath & "*.txt")
 Do While currentFile <> ""
' Import text file
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & currentPath & currentFile, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete

' Copy values to main data table

    Sheet3.Range("A2:P2").Copy

    Sheet6.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheet6.Activate

    'move the file
    Name currentPath & currentFile As newPath & currentFile
    'get the next file
    currentFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick! (I had to adjust my "Clear previous data" code to move it down so it fell after getting the first file.)